# Getting java.net.ConnectException when running word count program in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I was trying to run word count program in spark streaming, but I am getting below error.I was using nc -lk 9999

```
           import org.apache.spark._
           import org.apache.spark.streaming._
           import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
           import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds


                object wordcount{

                def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {


         val conf = new 
      SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("WordCount")
      val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))

              val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",9999)

              val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
                    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
                    val wordcount = pairs.reduceByKey(_+_)

         wordcount.print()

        ssc.start()             
             ssc.awaitTermination()
```

> WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Error connecting to localhost:9999
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.SocketReceiver.receive(SocketInputDStream.scala:73)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.SocketReceiver$$anon$2.run(SocketInputDStream.scala:59)

Comment: Can this be edited into a readable format?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue once.
This exception occurs when you are connecting spark to port `999` netcat server but you have not started it yet. So, ensure that your `netcat` is running before connecting spark to port `999`.

You can have a look on this solution [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632824/connection-refused-error-while-running-spark-streaming-on-local-machine)

Comment: You can check that whether you have given correct port number or not. And it would be good if you could share your code.

Comment: import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds


 object wordcount{
  
  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {
    

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("WordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))

val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",9999)

val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordcount = pairs.reduceByKey(_+_)

wordcount.print()

ssc.start()   sc.awaitTermination()

Comment: you can see my question at the top of this page which is clear